# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'ano'

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, cql, cqlsh

I get this error in the spark 3.0.0:

ERRO1:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'ano'.
> This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a
> permanent function registered in the database 'sspkeyspace'.; line 1
> pos 58

I created a UDF in Cassandra DB 3.11.9 to extract the year of the date column:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ano (input DATE)
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE java AS 'return input.toString().substring(0,4);';
```

I ran the query in the cqlsh prompt :

```sql
select  ano(data_compra) as ano from Compras ;
```

and it's worked well. However in the spark, into the application, shows the ERRO1.

Result Query in the cql prompt:

```
ano
-----
2014
2009
2013
2012
2014
2012
2011
2019
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work this way - when you execute `select  ano(data_compra) as ano from Compras` in Spark, it's considering the `ano` function as Spark function, not as the Cassandra UDF function.

Unfortunately, to expose UDF to Spark SQL, you will need to write some code for Spark Cassandra Connector itself.  Instead, it's better to re-implement the needed functionality in Spark itself, just replace usage of `ano` call with call to built-in Spark [substring](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#substring) - it could be even more performant.

Comment: thanks to share the link. I need to convert the date first and than to use the substring. It is so big, but it's works. The function: substring(TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data_compra, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS TIMESTAMP)),1,4) as ano.

Comment: @LucianaOliveira It seems you want to get the year from the date, then in spark simply use [`year`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#year) function: `select year(data_compra) as ano from Compras` (no need for substring)

Comment: Agree with @blackbishop - if your dates are in correct format, then `year` would be better

Comment: @blackbishop, thanks for you reply. I change the expression to 'year'. It's much better now. I'm gratefulness.

Answer (score 1):

Check where your function is registered if it is , use this command :

```
SHOW USER FUNCTIONS;
```

if It is registered use the root then . to get access to the function:

By default it is:

```
select  default.ano(data_compra) as ano from Compras ;
```

Comment: @itlsNaz, I ran "SHOW USER FUNCTIONS;" command in the cqlsh prompt and returned this message :"the Improper SHOW command." . I used the "describe functions;" command and returned the functions that I created. All are in the root.

Comment: no you need to find the function in spark udf, by the way I supposed that you know that to integrate spark and cassandra you need a connector , if you don't see what i talking about you need to configure your connector  , take a look to this link: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md  , after configuring the connector use spark.sql(""" your query """) and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, to share the link. I configurated the connector, but your replay help me to find the answer. I used this fuction in the sql.spark : substring(TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data_compra, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS TIMESTAMP)),1,4) as ano.

Comment: However it is not my inicial question. I was converting a SQL query (relational BD) to CQL query (cassandra+spark). And in SQL the function is native, and is so simple. But converter in string (in spark) was the solution kkkk. Thanks a lot!